# Creating an MLP that learns based on GPS coordinates

Tags: gps, neural-network

I have some data that tells me the amount of hours water is available for particular towns. 
You can see it [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AqDm6Izoam4OdFBJb3dsRkd6WlNGU0xXdzNmWWxpTnc&single=true&gid=0&output=html)

I want to use train a Multilayer Perceptron based on that data, to take a set of coordinates and indicate the approximate number of hours for which that coordinate will have water.

Does this make sense?
If so, am I correct in saying, there has to be two input layers? One for lat and one for long.  And the output layer should be the number of hours.

Would love some guidance.

Comment: Do you want o have a time dependency too? Is there a time stamp in your data, and does this change? So do you have watherHours per cooridnate with timestamp?

Comment: What the current state of your apporach? Does it work? IS MLP usefull for that task? (Consider also upvoting my answer), since you have accepted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve that differently: 
Just create an ArrayList of WaterInfo:
WaterInfo contains lat,lon, waterHours.
Then for a given coordinate search the closest WaterInfo in the list.
Since you have not many elements, just do a brute force search, to find the closest.
You further can optimize, to find the three closest WaterInfo points, and calculate the weithted average of WaterHours. As weight you use the air distance from current position to Waterinfo position.

To answer your question:

> "Does this makes sense"?

From the goal to get a working solution: NO!
Ask yourself, why do you want to use MLP for this task.

Further i doubt that using two layers for lat / long makes sense.
A coordinate (lat/lon) is one point on the world, so that should be one layer in the model. You can convert the lat/lon coord to a cell identifier: Span a grid over Brazil; with cell width 10 or 50km; now convert a lat/long coordinate to a cellId: Like E4 on a chess board, you will calculate one integer value representing the cell.
 (There are other solutions to get an unique number, too, choose one you like)

Now you have a modell geoCellID -> waterHours, which better represents the real world situation.

Comment: I'm required to use MLPs for my solution. Also, the number of coords will grow to a couple hundred.

Comment: a couple of hundred is nothing, a couple of millions, would require a spatial index. a couple of hundred allows brute force. Why are you required to use MLP? company or university project? (Master thesis?); are you interested in a working solution, or more to check how an MLP approach will work?

Comment: Hmm, @AlexWien, this is helpful stuff, but if I can use two inputs in an XOR, why can't I use two inputs here? (Oh, this is for a university project, which is why i have to use MLP)

Comment: @Irwin I have not enough insight how later the data will be queried or visualized. Don't forget latitude and longitude do not have the same scale (only in north brazil at the aequator), lat/lon are coordinates on a spehere. If that is a problem you can convert with tranverse Mercator projection or maybe UTM, to get a linear scale in meters. More i cannot help you.

Comment: Thanks for all the help @AlexWien, I used some of the info from your answer, together with more research to train my MLP.